# is there any way to define dynamic array without Determine the size of it

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I need a dynamic array that I don't have to scale(Determine) to a fixed number like the following

```
string* s;
```

I have this code so far, but obviously it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("resa.txt");
    string* s;
    int i = 0;
    while (f.good())
    {
        f >> *(s + i);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my task:

> Now we change the class definitions a bit. No static arrays can occur anymore. The fact that the arrays instead become dynamic means that some class methods need to be modified, and that some / some of the classes need copy constructors and assignment methods (or superimposed assignment operator). [...]"

This means, that I just can't use data structures.

Comment: no, i just can't use data structures!!

Comment: Why not? What *can* you use?

Comment: I put the Task link in the edit, you will see what I'm talking about in the last line, I hope you get what I mean

Comment: Just a hint: Using the entire std namespace is considered [bad practice](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Just import what you need.

Comment: It would make more sense if you would just copy the task or the rules as such in the question instead of providing this image. This is also better for SEO. I edited your post.

Comment: Looks like you want a terrible, non-exception-safe version with raw pointers and new/delete. [Here you go](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WGahde)

Comment: I wanted it but it is 16 pages so I don't think it is possible to publish all of this in a question, anyway Thank you very much for your help and your advice too. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not automatic, you have to allocate more memory every time you want to resize, copy elements into new array and delete the old one. Fortunately, standard library got you covered with [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) - an automatically resizable array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("resa.txt");
    string temp;
    std::vector<std::string> s;
    while (f >> temp)
    {
        s.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also fixed your input reading - see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) (applies to `good()` as well).

---

Alternatively, you can use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to initialize vector in one line instead of using loop (credit to [Ayxan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10147399/ayxan)):

```
vector<string> s{ istream_iterator<string>{f}, {} };
```

Comment: How about `vector<string> s{ istream_iterator<string>{f}, {} };`

Comment: @Ayxan Added. I wanted to keep it simple (omitted `std::move` for that), but your solution is a cool oneliner :)

Comment: Is there no other way without using data structures ???

Comment: @AboudAl-Salem Any language-level construct that allowed the behavior you want would have to do the same thing one of the standard containers does.  If you want to store data you have to have memory to put it in, which means expanding the size of the structure requires either a node-based linked structure or copying the data around, and each has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @AboudAl-Salem Well, you want a data structure - an array of `std::string` (and `std::string` is a data structure itself). If you don't want `std::vector` or another STL container, you will end up reimplementing vector yourself - `new` an array of strings, read next element, `new` bigger array, copy existing elements, `delete` old array, read next element, `new` bigger array...

Comment: Oh well, so I think that's what I'm supposed to do, thank you very much